# Find the equation of intersection of a torus and a circle on a plane without using iterative methods.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the equation of a circle on the plane (where $p_0$ is the centre, $\theta$ is the angle of the circle, and $w$ and $v$ are pair of orthogonal vectors from $p_0$ to the circle (having equal length).

$$p_0 + \cos(\theta)v + \sin(\theta)w$$

Changing format this gives

$$p_0 + \frac{1-s^2}{1+s^2}v + \frac{2s}{1+s^2}w$$

I also have the equation of the torus

$$x^4 + 2x^2y^2 + 2x^2z^2 - 2(R^2 + r^2)x^2 + y^4 + 2y^2z^2 - $$
$$-2(R^2 + r^2)y^2 + z^4 +2(R^2 - r^2z^2) + (R^2 - r^2)^2$$

Substituting the equation of the circle into the torus gives an 8th order equation, however its possible to reduce this to a 4th order equation given that  v.w =0 and  v.v = w.w this can then be solved using a quartic equation solver.
My problem is reducing the order of the equation, I can remove some of the higher order terms using v.w=0 but I can’t seem to work out how to reduce the equation order using v.v = w.w, and definitely not get a 4th order equation.
Any help you could supply would be gratefully appreciated.